# Rust: Implicitly convert from usize to the corresponding int type

Tags: rust

I wonder if anyone has a solution to allow implicit conversion from usize type (that we obtain from accessing array index, or getting vector length) to i32 ? Is it even possible?

Of course I assume that vector length and array bounds are within i32 limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) trait in function arguments to do implicit conversions from the perspective of callers. It still involves conversion, but it moves the complexity to the function being called:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn stuff(val: impl TryInto<i32>) {
    // use try_into trait method
    let val = match val.try_into() {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => panic!("couldn't fit in i32"),
    };
    println!("in stuff: val has {} leading zeros", val.leading_zeros());
}

fn main() {
    let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let len = letters.len();
    println!("in main: len has {} leading zeros", len.leading_zeros());
    stuff(len); // implict conversion
}
```

outputs

```
in main: len has 62 leading zeros
in stuff: val has 30 leading zeros
```

[Try on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a8889b4750752c64a570368a0f61f6d)

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! Any solution for indexes of arrays though?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I don't think that implict conversion is possible for array indexing since the array indexing implementation is done in the standard library.

Comment: Ok, also TryInto seems to be the reverse of TryFrom, but wouldn't it be more efficient with `as` keyword (since we know that the conversion would work)? something like: `fn stuff(val:usize as i32) {`

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: Why do you *know* the conversion will work? An *arbitrary* `usize` might have a value greater than `i32` can hold. Rust has to make the interface safe no matter who calls it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Precisely because the usize is not arbitrary. (for example if it was an i32 converted to usize previously)

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: The *function* can't know that. If using the function with arbitrary `usize`s is inherently unsafe, Rust isn't going to make it *easy* to do. The way you prove that the value is safe is to keep it as an `i32` the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do it implicitly. If there is, it wouldn't be very idiomatic: Rust decided to avoid implicit conversions and ensure that all conversions are done explicitly.

For straightforward conversions, `as` is probably the best bet. For conversions where you're concerned about overflow, etc. you've got `From` and `TryFrom`. For small lengths converting to `i32`, `length as i32` is probably the easiest.

It does make stuff a bit more verbose, but I find it's a fairly good compromise.

There's a good writeup in the Rust book on `as` here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html#casting

Comment: "a bit more verbose" is an understatement ;)